# Blackberry Facebook SDK cannot getCurrentUser

Tags: facebook, blackberry, sdk

I'm developing an application for OS 6 and 7 that requires Twitter and Facebook integration. It's been a complete nightmare because they seem very temperamental. Last week they were working perfectly, but now the facebook integration broke (code was untouched).
The only thing that may have changed is the Java Compiler level.

The following code is what I'm using. The browser displays `NEXT_URL` but the code blocks at `user = fb.getCurrentUser();`. When I close the browser the exception says "unable to refresh access token".

```
String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
String APPLICATION_ID = "xxxxxxx";
String APPLICATION_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
String[] PERMISSIONS = Facebook.Permissions.PUBLISHING_PERMISSIONS;
ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID,APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);

Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);
User user;
try
{
    user = fb.getCurrentUser();
    user.publishStatus(msg);
} catch (Exception e)
{
    Dialog.inform(e.getMessage());
} finally
{
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().close();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Turns out the key and secret supplied by the client weren't correct. But since the app was identified by Facebook and able to log in, I think it was the secret. Will get on their faces now.